# makebox and framebox LaTeX equivalent in ConteXt

Tags: context, boxes

What is the equivalent to `\makebox[s]` and `\framebox[s]` stretching text in ConTeXt.

For example :

```tex
\makebox[5cm][s]{some contents}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if ConTeXt has an interface for it, but with the `\hbox` primitive it's quite straightforward. If you need nice frames, wrap a `\framed` and *voilà*.

**Edit**: Wolfgang suggested `align=paragraph`, so I'll include it too.

```
\starttext
%%% Low level
\hbox to 5cm{Some text}
\framed[offset=0cm]{\hbox to 5cm{Some more text}}
%%% Cleaner, better
\framed[width=5cm,align=paragraph,frame=off]{Some text}
\framed[width=5cm,align=paragraph]{Some text}
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched the ConTeXt mailing list and found [this post by Luigi Scarso](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg64456.html).
AFAIU, the following MWE solves your problem. The two first lines look like TeX solution to me — but I am no boxing wizard at all. I added two lines on my own, using ConTeXt `\framed`

```
\starttext
\hbox to 4cm{\hsize=4cm\stretched{some text}}

\ruledhbox to 5cm{\hsize=5cm\stretched{to the limit}}

\blank[big]

\framed[width=4cm]{\hsize=4cm\stretched{some text}}

\framed[width=4cm,frame=off]{\hsize=4cm\stretched{some text}}
\stoptext
```